# Leaflet/AngularJS - Auto user location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to follow the Leaflet procedure given [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html)  with a great [working example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile-example.html) to automatically locate use in my Ionic app. 
However I have some trouble finding the correct syntax to embeed the code given on the leaflet page with mine. 
Thanks for you help.

**EDIT SOLUTION**: easy way is using the "[center autodiscover](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/center-autodiscover-example.html) " directive in Angular

JS

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, leafletEvents) {
var map = L.map('map');
$scope.eventStatus = 'Map View';

angular.extend($scope, {
    defaults: {
        tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        maxZoom: 18,
        path: {
            weight: 10,
            color: '#800000',
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    });

 function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});


});
```

HTML:

```
    <ion-list>  
        <ion-item class="leaflet_custom_container">
            <div class="" ng-controller="MapCtrl" > <!-- -->
                <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"   >
                    <leaflet  defaults="defaults" height="450px" width="600px"  >
                    </leaflet>

            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```